# Does independence on semi rings imply independence on the generated sigma algebras?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a set and let $M$ be a sigma algebra on it. That is, $M$ contains $\emptyset$, $M$ is closed under complements and $M$  is closed under countable unions. Furthermore assume that $P$ is a probability measure on $M$. Now we define a semi ring $A$ as a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ such that $A$ contains $\emptyset$, $A$ is closed under finite intersections and such that for all $S, T \in A$ we have that $S \setminus T$ can be written as a finite disjoint union of elements of $A$.

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be two semi rings contained in $M$ and assume that for all $S_1 \in A_1$ and all $S_2 \in A_2$ we have that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are independent; $P(S_1 \cap S_2) = P(S_1)P(S_2)$.

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be the sigma algebras generated by $A_1$ and $A_2$ respectively.

> Does independence of the semi rings carry over to the sigma algebras generated by them? That is, does it hold that for all $S_1 \in M_1$ and all $S_2 \in M_2$ we have $P(S_1 \cap S_2) = P(S_1)P(S_2)$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the independence carries over. In fact, the collections $A_1$ and $A_2$ don't need to be semi-rings, just closed under finite intersections. You can find a proof in **Lemma 3.6** on page 50 of *Foundations of Modern Probability (2e)* by Olav Kallenberg.

Alternatively, see Theorem 2.1.3 (p. 39) of 
*Probability: Theory and Examples (4th edition)*
by Richard Durrett. The book is [freely available at the author's website.](http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe write the proof here as well, for those of us who don't own _Foundations of Modern Probability (2e)_?